# How do I look up the hsync/vsync values for my monitor?

Tags: xorg, configuration, resolution, monitor

I'm trying to get my computer to use the correct resolution. For that I need to specify the horizontal and vertical sync values in the configuration file (`xorg.conf`):

```
Section "Monitor"  
  Identifier     "Monitor0"  
  VendorName     "Unknown"  
  ModelName      "CRT-0"  
  HorizSync       31.0 - 81.0  
  VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0  
  Option         "DPMS"  
EndSection
```

Let's say these values for `HorizSync` and `VertRefresh` are somehow wrong for my monitor.
**Where do I find the correct values?**

*Note: This is a "dummy" question -- with the help from the chat, I already found part of the answer, and I am now going to add my own answer to document a solution that is hopefully universal.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your monitor's manual.

If it's not there, find out if there are identically built models on the market, or just stick to the default values (they're quite safe and reasonable for almost anything with a VGA connector).

However, before doing it this "hard way", check whether your monitor and video card can't negotiate everything by themselves.

Comment: Ha, I wanted to provide an answer to my own question but you beat me to it :-)

Comment: If it is not in your manual, or if like me you *somehow* misplaced the manual that came with your monitor =) ; google your monitor and you should find the specifications.

Comment: What if it is a laptop monitor? I don't see such information listed under the laptop specs