# How do I set the correct monitor resolution with Nvidia drivers for a monitor that does not send EDID?

Tags: xorg, configuration, resolution, monitor

I keep having trouble getting the correct monitor resolution - every time I reinstall, I happen to use a newer Ubuntu release and the old tricks I used to know no longer work. Instead of leaving a long trail of questions for every new release, I am looking for a more universal and timeless solution.

**What's the correct way to set the correct monitor resolution with an Nvidia GPU for a screen that does not send EDID values?**

*Note: This is a "dummy" question -- with the help from the chat, I already found the answer, and I am now going to add my own answer to document a solution that is hopefully universal.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow these steps.

Note that **steps 6 and 7 are not usually necessary;** try skipping them and if that does not work, repeat all steps and include these two. Some monitors don't send EDID information to the computer, so Ubuntu can't know what the monitor is capable of and only offers safe (low) resolutions. Those two steps resolve that problem.

1. Reboot and restart in `Recovery Mode`.
2. Type `rm /etc/X11/xorg.xonf` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. Type `reboot` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
4. Once you're at the normal Ubuntu desktop again, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `terminal` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)
5. In the terminal, type `sudo nvidia-xconfig` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>). This will write a new `xorg.conf` file.
6. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>).
7. Look for the part beginning with `Section "Monitor"`and there enter the correct `HorizSync` and `VertRefresh` values. (See [How do I look up the hsync/vsync values for my monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100898/how-do-i-look-up-the-hsync-vsync-values-for-my-monitor))
8. Restart.
9. Once you're at the normal Ubuntu desktop again, find *"Nvidia X Server Settings"* in the *"start menu"* and start that.
10. In the section `X Server Display Configuration`, set the desired resolution and press the button `Save to X Configuration File`.
11. Reboot.

You should now have the proper resolution!

Finally, copy the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to a safe place in case you mess it up later and need to restore it.

Answer (score 2):

## Using nVidia settings application

If your computer has the nvidia propietary drivers, you should have `nvidia-settings` installed and ready.

### Command-line method

Run the following command:

```
nvidia-settings --query FlatpanelNativeResolution
```

If this returns nothing, or an error, try to look for valid attributes with:

```
nvidia-settings --query all | grep -i resolution
```

Then try the first command with one of the found attributes that sounds adequate.

### GUI method

1. Open `nvidia-settings`, either by looking for its launcher or running it as a command.
2. In the section tree, go to your GPU.
3. Now either browse all the items or look for an item which sounds like a device name, in my case I see `DFP-0 (AUO)`.
4. You will now see under **Flatpanel Information** a list of resolutions.

Comment: `nvidia-settings --query all` returns nothing

Comment: I didn't find any setting with name resolution, when grep it. 
@severo-raz

Comment: I found it as `CurrentMetaMode`
Thanks a lot anyway.
`Attribute 'CurrentMetaMode' (maxpc:0.0): id=50, switchable=no, source=nv-control :: DPY-0: 3840x2160_60_0 @3840x2160 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=3840x2160, ViewPortOut=3840x2160+0+0}`

Answer (score 0):

- Open `nvidia-settings` from app menu or thru console.
- Choose the monitor and set desired resolution and other parameteres:
- Click "**Save to X configuration file**". Here I had some difficulties with saving file, despite running `nvidia-settings` as root and trying to save in places I definitely had right to write.
- Thus I clicked **Show previev...** on save window, copied contents and saved in

  `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/nvidia.conf` (you can use any resonable filename in this path)
- did `init 3` and `init 5`or restart, if you prefere.
- E voila, desired screen parametres are persistent.