# nVidia Dual Monitor Resolution Problem

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04. I have two monitors and the monitor on the left has a different resolution and I can't change it. (See: screen shot)

[image]

Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected primary 640x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        59.9*+
   320x240        60.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1080+640+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found. Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/100900/how-do-i-set-the-correct-monitor-resolution-with-nvidia-drivers-for-a-monitor-th