# Incorrect resolution for second display after using NVidia Driver in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nvidia, 17.10

I am using: 
Ubuntu 17.10 
Driver: nvidia-384
Card: GTX770m.

1st Issue: after I upgraded to (nvidia-384) driver, the second display does not show the full resolution (1920x1080). And maximum shown resolution is (1360x768).

2nd issue: Screen mirror mode disappeared too.

[image]

Comment: have you tried updating the driver to nvidia-390? they possibly could have fixed some display detection issues.

Comment: Yes i upgraded to 18.04 yesterday which upgraded the driver, however still the same issue

Comment: This is more of a temporary workaround so I won't post it as an answer, but you might be able to simply force it using [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100900/how-do-i-set-the-correct-monitor-resolution-with-nvidia-drivers-for-a-monitor-th).