# Nvidia drivers reset after update and now monitor is "unknown" and stuck in 640x480

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

I had a software update to my system (Ubuntu 20.04) that, after running, failed, and my system now is only seeing my monitor on VGA (I also have an HDMI display that is my main display) and reading it out at "unknown display" and the only resolution option is 640X480.

Running Xrandr gives

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00*
```

and trying the method here [How do I set the correct monitor resolution with Nvidia drivers for a monitor that does not send EDID?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100900/how-do-i-set-the-correct-monitor-resolution-with-nvidia-drivers-for-a-monitor-th/100907#100907) does not change anything.
When I try to run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
this is what I get

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04-edge : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (<= 460.32.03-1) but it is not going to be installed
                                                   Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (>= 460.32.03) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-driver-460 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (<= 460.32.03-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (>= 460.32.03) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-460 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (= 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I first tried running autoinstall, it was blocked as dpkg was still in use by apt even after it restarted after update.

Following is the output of `ubuntu-drivers devices`

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:05:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001244sv0000196Esd0000089Cbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF116 [GeForce GTX 550 Ti]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000014E4d000043A0sv00001043sd000085DFbc02sc80i00
vendor   : Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
model    : BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
driver   : bcmwl-kernel-source - distro non-free
```

**Update/Solution**
So I was pretty sure I had remembered having a similar problem before.
Turns out the answer is that I had to uninstall the Nvidia drivers and use nouveau--problem was the update has an update to the nvidia driver, which the system then defaulted to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution (for me) here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=339381&start=20

If combined:

- Pick the Nouveau driver in "Additional drivers"
- Run `sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*`
- Reboot
- Run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-460`
- Pick Nvidia 460 driver
- Reboot

Optional (after installing `nvidia-driver-460`):

- Run `sudo apt install nvidia-kernel-source-460`
- Run `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460`
- Run `sudo apt install libnvidia-cfg1-460`

It worked for me 14 minutes ago, everything works as usual :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. You need the correct nvidia driver installed.

If you don't already have aptitude installed, you can install it with "sudo apt install aptitude".
My solution was to use the the command "sudo aptitude install libgl1". Which is for the decencies. It will then offer you a solution to accept. Accept it and try to install the nvidia driver manually with "sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460". If that doesn't work, run "sudo aptitude install libgl1" again and do not accept the first solution and try the second one. Repeat until you find one that works. Mine ended up being to downgrade the packages then install.

You can also try completing uninstall the nvidia drivers using "sudo apt remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'" or "sudo nvidia-uninstall". Then try installing ubuntu-desktop with "sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop" or using "sudo ubuntu-drivers-autoinstall"

Comment: No luck on those, uninstalling using purge then doing the auto install at least allowed auto install to work, but no change to display usablility

Comment: Try just plugging in the HDMI monitor to see if the same problem occurs on HDMI?

Comment: I had tried that. HDMI was not even seen. Issue is the nvidia drivers period

Answer (score 0):

Needed to just use the nouveau drivers.
So solution is

```
sudo nvidia-uninstall 
reboot
```

Thanks to Benhamin1029

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem on Ubuntu 20.04, to be sure that we have the same issue try the following command:

```
nvidia-smi
```

If you get error, then I think the following steps will help you (for me the answers above did not help):

```
 - sudo apt remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'

 - sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*
```

Now you have to download cuda from here:
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
This should be something similar to:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.2.1/local_installers/cuda_11.2.1_460.32.03_linux.run
```

After the download is complete run:

```
sudo sh cuda_11.2.1_460.32.03_linux.run
```

Accept, next next etc. If you get an error try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

and then again

```
sudo sh cuda_11.2.1_460.32.03_linux.run
```

After successful install reboot your computer, everything should be fine.