# Upgrade gone wrong

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu

First question here. I recently upgraded from Xubuntu-18.04 to Xubuntu-20.04.  When the upgrade was finished, and I rebooted, I had no video. The monitor displayed "Out of Range" message.  I found that if I rebooted into Rescue mode that I could get to a Desktop, but I was stuck on a 640x480 display that could'nt be changed.

After a lot of research, I stumbled onto a clue about adding "nolapic" as a kernel parameter.  It worked.  I can get to a desktop that is 1024x768 and that is acceptable.  However, if I need to log out of the Desktop for any reason, the monitor again displays the"Out of Range" message.  And the only way I can get back to the Desktop is to press CTL-ALT-F1 to get to a terminal login screen, login and issue a sudo reboot command.

If anyone has a suggestion as to how I can boot into the system, logout, if I need to, and still be able to login without rebooting, I would very much appreciate it.  Thanks for your time.

Here is the ouput of lshw -C display:

```
'''*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: C77 [GeForce 8300]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:5 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:d8000000-dfffffff memory:e6000000-e7ffffff ioport:dc00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
'''
```

Is this what you wanted to see, HuHa ?

Thank you all for your patience and for your answers.  No matter what I did I could not get Xubuntu-20.04 to play nice on this computer.  I have gone back to Xubuntu-18.04.  It works.  It's not a great solution, but at this point it's a necessary one. I need a computer that works.

Comment: Please add what graphics card you have and the output of `lspci` and of `sudo lshw -C display`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Being new here, I don't know how to attach the output of either of those 2 commands so that you can see them.

Comment: You could try a live system (e.g. your Ubuntu installation USB stick) and start a browser from there so you can copy and paste the output of those commands here.

Comment: Please add that information to your question so experts trying to find an answer can see everything relevant there. Please add a line with 3 backticks before and after the output so it remains formatted as it was in the shell.

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/100900/